# Segues and transmitting data between UI Views. [Map Kit]

Tags: swift, delegates, segue

I am very new to swift so if you could explain this to me simply that would be great. 
I am trying to build an app with map kit that will have around 20 pins with different locations. So far, I have managed to create a pin with an annotation, stating its name, a subtitle and a info button.

Now I am trying to get the "info" button to link to a second UI view. Currently I only have it coded to print text as shown below:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view:      MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl){
    if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
        print("Button taaped ")
    }
```

I need to know how I can link the button to open a new UI I have created in the main story board, that will have different pictures, title and description depending on which pin is clicked. If someone could explain this simply I would be very grateful
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

create segue between both view controllers, and give it an identifier again from storyboard, then in your code instead of print, call perform segue with identifier function and pass the identifier string exactly as you typed it in the storyboard

Comment: Do I create the segue in the storyboard? Does this mean I need an individual UI View for all 20 pins?

Comment: no, only one segue between the map view controller and the details view controller

Comment: and pass details of each pin to details view controller in the method prepare for segue

Comment: Oh so within the method i would have to have if loops for each segue identifier right? eg: _if segue.identifier == big ben then otherview.image = bigben_

Answer (score 0):

On the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped:` you can call:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view:  MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl){
if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue for otherView identifier", sender: view)
}
```

you going to send your annotationView to prepareForSegue.

After that you implement the method `prepareForSegue:`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segue for otherView identifier" {
        let annotationView = sender as! MKAnnotationView
        let otherView = segue.destinationViewController as! OtherviewController
        otherView.image = annotationView.image
        otherView.title = annotationView.annotation?.title
        otherView.description = annotationView.annotation?.subtitle
    }

}
```

You just need to make sure that on your `otherViewController` you have all the attributes that you want to receive form the other view (image, title, description)

Comment: `if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
             performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue for otherView identifier", sender: nil)` Like this? Also where do I implement this `prepareForSegue` method in the Second View Controller class?

Comment: Yes. You just need to change the String "segue for otherView identifier" for the segue identifier that you need to give to your segue when you are linking both view on the storyBoard. Also, you don't need to implement this method on the second view controller, you implement it on the first one.

Comment: Will this identifier have to be unique for all 20 pins? Or will I need 20 UI Views for one for each pin?  Also, is it arbitrary what string I use?

Comment: No. The identifier is like a name that you give to the segue, so that way you can refer to it on your code. So, you just need one. lets say that you are on your map view, and you click on the button of your annotation. It will trigger the segue and through the segue you will send the informations such as title, description to your next view

Comment: About the string, you can give whichever name you want.

Comment: Ah so I will need 20 `performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue for otherView identifier` sender: nil)' with each individual identifier defined, eg: _Big Ben, Empire State Building,ect_ and 20 `if segue.identifier == "segue for otherView identifier` for the description, image,ect? eg: _Big Ben, Located in London, image of Big Ben_

Comment: I seem to be struggling trying to implement the `prepare for segue` method as I am getting an error stating **Method does not override any method from its superclass** and I am unsure how to name the Second View Controller hence it does not know what second view controller is.

Comment: No! you don't need to do 20 times anything, lol. Do you know how to create a segue and gives it a identifier?

Comment: If I dont explicitly state what image is needed for which segue identifier how will it know which images to use?

Comment: Your annotation has all the information that it need. It has the image for that annotations, the title and description. So, all you need to do is send this information to your prepareForSegue, and you will be able to send to the other view the exactly image and other stuff from that annotation. I edited the answer. Take a look!

Comment: Ok so I watched a tutorial and linked the two UI views using a segue, I named the second UI view "Info Page" and put `performSegue(withIdentifier: "Info Page", sender:self)`  inside the MapView function. However now when I click the button, it jumps me to the View Controller (showing possibly the stack?) of information and it does this no matter value I set to **withIdentifier:** do you know what would cause this?

Comment: I don't think my annotation has that? I have just defined it as the following: `let artworkPin = Artwork(title:"Wind Wand",locationName:"Majestic",discipline:"Statue",
                                 coordinate:windwandcoord)`  I planned to set a description, and image elsewhere. If you wish I could send you my whole code or message you on skype? Thanks for your help btw it has been incredibly useful